# Subclassing UIAlertController

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

With pre-iOS 8 we had to use the `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet`

Which we weren't allowed to mess with the view hierarchy or subclass on either them.

[`UIAlertView` Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

[`UIActionSheet` Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html)

> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:.

However with iOS8 Apple have introduced `UIAlertController` to replace both `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet` (Check the pre-release documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014538-CH1-SW2)).

So in this pre-release documentation there is nothing about not being able to subclass or change the view heirarchy, it even has this method `addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:` so will we be able to change the view heirarchy and/or subclass `UIAlertController` without worrying whether Apple will approve or reject our applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer is outdated**. Please refer to [limon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34007621/106435).

---

<s>`ViewController != View`. Apple's policy of not changing the appearance of an `UIAlertView` does not affect the presenting view controller. I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to subclass the UIAlertController. But using it may be making it harder to replace the alert view with something custom grown, as the alert view is now only created indirectly by classes out of your control. And for UIAlertView [same rules applies as before](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView).</s>

Comment: I have given +1. However this is only because I have decided not to accept an answer until iOS8 is officially released. I hope when it is, this will have been confirmed and hopefully you will provide an up to date answer (If it is required)

Comment: Don't mean to intrude... but in relation to subclassing UIAlertController, I'm just after posting this question- any thoughts?

http://stackoverflow.com/q/26935703/343343

Comment: can sub-classing it cause App rejection?

Comment: in my experience anything can lead to a rejection. or not. you never know. But yes, a reviewer with a bad day might justify the rejection with this. or not. you never know.

Answer (score 29):

It's a late response, but directly from Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014538-CH1-SW2).

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

So, you shouldn't subclass UIAlertController.