# Subclassing UIAlertController and encountering runtime errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm new to programming for iOS and OSX, and decided to start with Swift and use the iOS8 API's for a test app and attempt some programming techniques I use in other environments. However, I'm encountering a strange situation which I hope someone could identify and help me with. This involves difficulties subclassing UIAlertController.

This was my first attempt:

```
import UIKit

class FubarAlertController: UIAlertController {

    convenience init (message:String) {
        self.init(title: "Alert", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        self.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    }
}
```

However, I got the following warnings in Xcode, which I don't understand- to my eyes, the errors appear to me to be self contradictory (pardon the bad pun)

```
use of self in delegating initializer before self.init is called
Self.init is't called on all paths in delegating initialiser
```

So then I tried

```
class FubarAlertController: UIAlertController {

    convenience init (message:String) {
        self.init();
        self.title = "Alert";
        self.message = message;
        self.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    }
}
```

and did not encounter any compile time errors. However, when I use this from a simple ViewController like so

```
class FubarController: UIViewController {

    // method invoked when a UIBarButtonItem action takes place 

    @IBAction
    func enterTextButtonAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let controller = FubarAlertController(message: "Fubar!");
        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }   
}
```

I get the following runtime error which again, I don't quite understand

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', 
reason: 'Your application has presented a UIAlertController
(<UiToolKit.TextChangedAlertController: 0x7adf2340>) of style 
UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The modalPresentationStyle of a 
UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You 
must provide location information for this popover through the alert 
controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a 
sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is
not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the 
UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'
```

But, if I simply implement FubarAlertController with no methods or properties at all, I can call it exactly as if it were a UIAlertController in the interface builder action like so

```
class FubarController: UIViewController {

    // method invoked when a UIBarButtonItem action takes place 

    @IBAction
    func enterTextButtonAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let controller = FubarAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Fubar!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }   
}
```

... and everything works as expected - no compile time or run time errors but I don't understand why!

So my questions are:

(i) Why couldn't I implement the convenience init method in the manner of my first attempt? What magic knowledge am I missing here? Why couldn't I call a super class init method in the context of self within a convenience initialiser?

(ii) How come I get run time as opposed to compile time errors when I subclass UIAlertController as I implemented it the second time?

Many thanks for making it this far and looking forward to some feedback - I'm stumped!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but thought it could use at least a partial answer.

(I) I've had to do the same as you to get a subclass of UIAlertController working. I think the simple answer is "Don't do it". Apple technically doesn't allow subclassing of UIAlertController, as per their documentation:

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

(II)
I got this same error when running my working iPhone app on iPad.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', 
reason: 'Your application has presented a UIAlertController of style 
UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. The modalPresentationStyle of a 
UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover. You 
must provide location information for this popover through the alert 
controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a 
sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this information is
not known when you present the alert controller, you may provide it in the 
UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method -prepareForPopoverPresentation.'
```

Since a popover on iPad is not full screen, iPad needs the `sourceView` or `sourceRect` property set to determine where on screen the popover should show from.

Add some code like this to your UIAlertController whenever you set the style to .ActionSheet:

```
//For iPad, check that there is a popover and set action button as the sender
if let popoverController = controller.popoverPresentationController {
        //Sender will be a UIButton, cast down to UIView
        popoverController.sourceView = sender as? UIView
        popoverController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
}
```

You may have to tweak this, depending your situation. My example above came from a IBAction function where `sender` is a UIButton.